# Instantiating android media player crashing app

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

The following code crashes, but does not if I comment all the lines instantiating media players. All the sound files are in /res/raw. They all autocomplete. They all play properly in Windows Media Player.

I've put toasts all over my code, and I seem to have tracked it down to any one of the MediaPlayer.create lines being not commented out.

I've also tried different things like declaring the instances public or private. Different ways of accessing the current context. Etc.

I must be missing something that will be obvious to someone else.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{

    RadioButton radio_button_1, radio_button_2, radio_button_3;
    Button play_button_1, play_button_2, play_button_3;
    RadioButton[] radio_button_list;
    Button[] play_button_list;


    //  public MediaPlayer bell_player = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.bell);
    MediaPlayer chainsaw_player = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.chainsaw);
    //  MediaPlayer harp_player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dream_harp);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in main activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Comment: What's the logcat say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiate the `MediaPlayer` object in the `onCreate()` method, instead of with a field initializer.

It requires a valid context, which the Activity doesn't have at that point.

Comment: Incidentally, I declared it as a field to expose it into the the onclicklisteners for some radio buttons. Now that won't work. Still trying to figure that one out.

Comment: Just declare the field, but initialize it in onCreate